# Fazendo Throttling a um método

Tags: c#, .net

Estava experimentando com o conceito de *throttling* e surgiram algumas dúvidas

- 1ª parte: Como traduzir numa única palavra este conceito?
- 2ª parte: Há alguma biblioteca que tenha uma implementação simples disso?

  - a minha tentativa pode ser encontrada em [github.com/pitermarx/Throttler](https://github.com/pitermarx/Throttler)

Comment: Uma possível tradução poderia ser "Dosagem", já que a tradução literal ("estrangulamento") não fica muito bem. Como você já implementou algo, o próximo passo é achar bons algoritmos de dosagem, o primeiro lugar em que eu iria procurar é em materiais sobre controle de banda de rede, pois eles têm de lidar com picos de demanda, manter médias, essa coisa toda.

Comment: Estrangulamento é o correto mas não é o que muita gente pensa quando pensa neste conceito. Não se trata de estrangular (ou dosear) os pedidos que se recebe mas sim os que se faz. Ou seja, não pressionar os sistemas a montante. Isto pode ser feito respondendo com valores pre-armazenados ou com erro mesmo se se ter chamando o sistema a montante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. De acordo com o [Tradutor Google](http://translate.google.com/#en/pt/throttle):

   > Throttle: regulador de pressão, válvula reguladora, reprimir, suprimir

   Não há uma tradução precisa de uma palavra só, mas eu definiria Throttle como "controle de sobretensão", da idéia de "surge control", em inglês.
2. Há a interface `IObservable`, que possui este método: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx